# Crear función constructora que no recibe, pero las propiedades deben generar un valor esperado

Tags: javascript

Crea una función constructora llamada Auto que no reciba ningún argumento pero inicializa una propiedad llamada velocidad en 0.

Agrega dos métodos al prototipo de la función constructora:

acelerar: recibe un número como argumento e incrementa la propiedad velocidad de acuerdo al número.
frenar: recibe un número como argumento y decrementa la propiedad velocidad de acuerdo al número. Sin embargo, si la velocidad terminara siendo negativa debe quedar en 0.

```js
    function Auto(){
      this.velocidad = 0
    }
    
    Auto.prototype.acelerar = function(numero) {
      this.velocidad += numero
    }
    
    Auto.prototype.frenar = function(numero){
      let result = this.velocidad -= numero 
      if( result<0){
        return 0
      }else{
        return result    
      }
    }
    
    // código de prueba
    const a1 = new Auto()
    console.log(a1.velocidad) // 0
    
    a1.acelerar(1)
    a1.acelerar(2)
    console.log(a1.velocidad) // 3
    
    a1.frenar(2)
    console.log(a1.velocidad) // 1
    a1.frenar(3)
    // la velocidad quedaría en -1, así que se deja en 0
    console.log(a1.velocidad) // 0
```

Mi problema es que en el ultimo console.log(a1.velocidad) el resultado deberia ser 0, pero me da -2

Comment: Tu problema es como estás usando la varaible `result`, podrías hacer la comparación sobre `this.velocidad` y devolver ese resultado. Result no está cumpliendo ninguna función en tu código... De hecho estás evaluando si esta variable es menor que cero para evitar  tener números negativos, pero nunca utilizas ese valor, utiliza la variable real `this.velocidad`

Answer (score 0):

En el método frenar no es necesario devolver un valor, solo analizar si el valor es mayor que velocidad y asignar o calcular la nueva velocidad. Puedes hacerlo con un if o con [asignación ternaria](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```js
function Auto(){
      this.velocidad = 0
    }
    
    Auto.prototype.acelerar = function(numero) {
      this.velocidad += numero
    }
    
    Auto.prototype.frenar = function(numero) {
      // Si número es mayor que velocidad, velocidad queda en cero
      // De lo contrario, restar numero
      this.velocidad = (numero > this.velocidad) ? 0 : this.velocidad - numero;
      // No es necesario devolver un valor
    }
    
    // código de prueba
    const a1 = new Auto()
    console.log(a1.velocidad) // 0
    
    a1.acelerar(1)
    a1.acelerar(2)
    console.log(a1.velocidad) // 3
    
    a1.frenar(2)
    console.log(a1.velocidad) // 1
    a1.frenar(3)
    // la velocidad quedaría en -1, así que se deja en 0
    console.log(a1.velocidad) // 0
```

Comment: Gracias Triby, por la explicación, exactamente cumple con la última condición